# finding the unique minimum value python

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a list of numbers.

```
lst=[1,1,2,4,8,2]
```

find the **unique** minimum value

Ideally the answer should be 4, But how do we get to 4?

Comment: Its not aduplicate, please review the question first, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Finding Lowest Unique Integer from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325817/python-finding-lowest-unique-integer-from-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
lst=[1,1,2,4,8,2]
print(min([i for i in set(lst) if lst.count(i) == 1]))
# --> 4
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did?
I can see a for loop, you changed the list to a set removing the duplicates

Comment: I am iterating each element of `lst` and filtering out the elements that have a count not equal to 1 and then applying `min`.

Comment: This works but is highly inefficient for large collections, leaving it here as a note.

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, how you do this is you first sort the list. And then you check from the lowest if the count == 1. If the count != 1 keep checking until you find the 'unique' number.

```
def get_lowest_and_unique(lst):
    for x in sorted(list(set(lst))):
        if lst.count(x) == 1:
            return x
    print("Could not find the correct element!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best option is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
lst=[1,1,2,4,8,2]
c = Counter(lst)
min(v for v, n in c.items() if n == 1)
4
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
t = list(set(lst))
list.sort(t)
unique_min = t[0]
```

Comment: This evaluates to 1 while the answer should be 4.

Comment: It's also the same, as regular ```min(lst)```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski It's the same as min(sorted(lst))

Comment: doing `set(lst)` makes **all** elements unique... You need to first filter-out the duplicates and then look for the minimum. @Philipp well, `min(sorted(lst))` and `min(lst)` should probably be the same thing...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is correct. I was thinking that min would be just accessing the first element for some reason.